# scala-native build failed in windwos with java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "which" error

Tags: scala, sbt, native, scala-native

When I build Scala native demo using sbt `rtlib/publishLocal` `nscplugin/publishLocal` it gives following error

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Scala code runner version `2.12.0-M3 -- Copyright 2002-2015, LAMP/EPFL`

Error

```
[info] Loading project definition from D:\Work\RandD\WSAMITScript\Scala-Native\scala-native\project
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "which": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.SimpleProcessBuilder.run(ProcessImpl.scala:349)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.lines(ProcessImpl.scala:149)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.lines_$bang(ProcessImpl.scala:143)
    at scala.scalanative.sbtplugin.ScalaNative
```

Comment: I don't see the demo requirements, but  if `which` is required, it won't build on Windows

Comment: Recipe for Debian Jessie with build instructions: http://github.com/frgomes/poc-scala-native

Answer (score 7):

Scala Native currently doesn't support Windows. Follow [the corresponding issue](https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native/issues/113) to track progress on that front.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried if it works inside a Cygwin terminal?